# Best practice for dealing with geolocation in offline mode

Tags: geolocation, gps, geocoding, android-gps

I have developed a mobile application allowing field agents to collect `data` based on `geolocation`.

Each agent is assigned to a specific point of sale where he has to go, and when he arrives, he has to point out his presence in this point of sale before starting the collection.

To detect that the agent is in the store, I used a `radius of 20 meters` to take into consideration `errors`, but the problem is that position detection isn't easy in `offline mode` and the user should `insist` for the position to be captured.Knowing that the `GPS chip` doesn't need internet to capture `location`.

My question is more about looking for advices and best practices if you've got some experience on these kind of applications.

In the Android phones especially i've increased the precision in the settings, but i'me having the same issues.

Notice : Online things are working good